# Unable to add effects in the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this simple javascript code to change the images in the slideshow in certain interval.then i tried adding some effects using css but it didn't work.Any tips or a small demo would be appreciated.Thank you!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var imagecount = 1;
    var total = 3;

    function slide(x) {
        var image = document.getElementById('img');
        imagecount = imagecount + x;
        if (imagecount > total) { imagecount = 1 }
        if (imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total }
        image.src = "img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
    }

    window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
        var image = document.getElementById('img');
        imagecount = imagecount + 1;
        if (imagecount > total) { imagecount = 1 }
        if (imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total }
        image.src = "img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
    }, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: which effects do you want specifically?

Comment: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/ and http://www.jssor.com/ There are TONS of effects here. Another way of switching through pictures (especially if you want a simple fade) is to animate `z-index`. I can give you code to do that if you want too?

Comment: i dont know the exact name but i wanted to change image slowly after the interval... i tried to use transition but didnt succeed .

Comment: @ctwheels i want to do it myself so i am not trying to use plugins... if you have the code then just give me the hints and important snippets so that i can work on it

Comment: @Kishor I am currently creating some code for a company project. I will post the code once I am done with it.

Comment: @Kishor I posted an answer below. Hopefully it helps you with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I finished it. There are a couple of small bugs (not big issues) with it and code might be a little messy at the moment (don't have time to clean up and boss wanted a full website up and running in less than 4 days) but it works. If you want the image fading effect without the pages, just remove pages and clean up code accordingly.

```js
var settings;
$(document).ready(function () {
    settings = {
        images: {
            structure: {
                id: "image-slider",
                active: "slider-image-active"
            },
            animation: {
                interval: 7000,
                effect: 1000
            },
            dimensions: {
                height: 0
            }
        },
        pages: {
            structure: {
                id: "page-slider",
                class: "featured",
                active: "slider-page-active",
                effect: "slider-page-effect"
            },
            animation: {
                interval: 7000,
                effect: 1000
            },
            dimensions: {
                minWidth: 200
            }
        }
    };
});
$(window).load(function () {
    resetImageSliderHeight();
    //setPageRows(settings);

    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        resetImageSliderHeight();

        var delay = (function () {
            var delayTimer = 0;
            return function (callback, ms) {
                clearTimeout(delayTimer);
                delayTimer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })();

        delay(function () {
            pageEffectFunction($('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.active));
        }, 500);
    });

    pageEffectFunction($('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.active));

    // run every 7s
    var timer = function () {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            cycleImages();
            cyclePages();
        },
        settings.images.animation.interval);
    };

    timer();

    $('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.class).stop(true).click(function () {

        pageEffectFunction($(this));

        cyclePagesImagesClick($(this));

        clearInterval(interval);
        timer();
    });
});


//IMAGES
function cycleImages() {
    var $active = $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' .' + settings.images.structure.active);
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img:first');
    /*$next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(settings.images.animation.effect, function () { //fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass(settings.images.structure.active); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass(settings.images.structure.active); //make the next image the top one
    });*/
    $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img:not(.' + settings.images.structure.active + ', :eq(' + ($next.index() - 1) + '))').css('z-index', 1);
    $active.css('z-index', 2);
    $next.css({
        'z-index': 3,
        display: 'none'
    }); //move the next image up the pile
    $next.fadeIn(settings.images.animation.effect, function () { //fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index', 1).removeClass(settings.images.structure.active); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.addClass(settings.images.structure.active); //make the next image the top one
    });

}

function resetImageSliderHeight() {
    settings.images.dimensions.height = getSmallestImageHeight(settings);
    setImageContainerHeight(settings);
}

function getSmallestImageHeight() {
    smallestImageHeight = 1000;
    $('#' + settings.images.structure.id).find('img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() < smallestImageHeight) smallestImageHeight = $(this).height();
    });
    return smallestImageHeight;
}

function setImageContainerHeight() {
    $('#' + settings.images.structure.id).find('img').each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).parent().height(settings.images.dimensions.height);
    });
}


function cyclePages() {
    var $active = $('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.active);
    var $element = $('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.class);
    var $next;
    if ($element.eq($element.index($("." + settings.pages.structure.active)) + 1).length > 0) {
        $next = $element.eq($element.index($("." + settings.pages.structure.active)) + 1);
    } else {
        $next = $element.eq(0);
    }
    //alert($next.html());
    $active.removeClass(settings.pages.structure.active, settings.pages.animation.effect);
    $next.addClass(settings.pages.structure.active, settings.pages.animation.effect);
    pageEffectFunction($next);
}

function cyclePagesImagesClick(element) {
    //Page
    var index = element.index() - 1;
    var $active = $('#' + settings.pages.structure.id + ' .' + settings.pages.structure.active);
    $active.removeClass(settings.pages.structure.active, settings.pages.animation.effect);
    element.addClass(settings.pages.structure.active, settings.pages.animation.effect);

    //Image
    var $imageElement = $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img').eq(index);
    $active = $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' .' + settings.images.structure.active);
    if ($active.index() != $imageElement.index()) {
        /*var $next = ($('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img').eq(index).next().length > 0) ? $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img').eq(index) : $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img').eq(0);*/
        $('#' + settings.images.structure.id + ' img:not(.' + settings.images.structure.active + ', :eq(' + ($imageElement.index() - 1) + '))').css('z-index', 1);
        $active.css('z-index', 2);
        $imageElement.css({
            'z-index': 3,
            display: 'none'
        }); //move the next image up the pile
        $imageElement.fadeIn(settings.images.animation.effect, function () { //fade out the top image
            $active.css('z-index', 1).removeClass(settings.images.structure.active); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
            $imageElement.addClass(settings.images.structure.active); //make the next image the top one
        });
    }
}

function pageEffectFunction(element) {
    var width = element.outerWidth();
    var height = element.outerHeight();
    var left = element.position().left;
    var top = element.position().top;
    $('#' + settings.pages.structure.effect).animate({
        left: left,
        top: top,
        width: width,
        height: height
    }, 200);
}
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
 #slider-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
#slider-container #image-slider {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider-container #image-slider-container {
    width: inherit;
}
#slider-container #image-slider-container #image-slider {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#slider-container #image-slider-container #image-slider img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: inherit;
}
#slider-container #image-slider-container #image-slider img.slider-image-active {
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .page-slider-row {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider #slider-page-effect {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #85BC2B;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    transition: background 0.45s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured:not(.slider-page-active):hover {
    background-color: #D3FEA0;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured.slider-page-active {
    background-color: none;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-right: 1px dashed #DCDCDC;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-text-container {
    padding: 15px 33px 27px;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-text-container .featured-title {
    color: #17513B;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured.slider-page-active .featured-text-container .featured-title {
    color: white;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-text-container .featured-description {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #51A351;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured.slider-page-active .featured-text-container .featured-description {
    color: white;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-link button.read-more {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    background: #62C462;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62C462, #51A351);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62C462, #51A351);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5;
    -moz-border-radius: 5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
    border: solid #008a05 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#slider-container #page-slider-container #page-slider .featured .featured-link button.read-more:hover {
    background: #62C462;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="image-slider-container">
        <div id="image-slider">
            <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Images Section" -->
            <img class='slider-image-active' src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Aerosol.png" alt="Yay I have info" />
            <img class="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Arpino_panorama.jpg" alt="Some alt thing" />
            <img class="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Bobbahn_ep.jpg" alt="Image of something" />
            <img class="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Cabreuva.jpg" alt="Soemthing" />
            <img class="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/DenglerSW-Peach-faced-Lovebird-20051026-1280x960.jpg" alt="Parrot" />
            <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-slider-container">
        <div id="page-slider">
            <div class="page-slider-row">
                <div id="slider-page-effect"></div>
                <div class="featured slider-page-active">
                    <div class="featured-text-container">
                        <div class="featured-title">
                             <h2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 0 Header" -->Some title<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-description">
                            <p>
                                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 0 Description" -->Some description, can be really long if i want it to!!! The boxes next to me will resize to my height, which I think is pretty darn cool!!!
                                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-link">
                        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 0 Link" --><a href="#">
            <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
            </a>

                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="featured">
                    <div class="featured-text-container">
                        <div class="featured-title">
                             <h2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 1 Header" -->Title 2<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-description">
                            <p>
                                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 1 Description" -->Description 2
                                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-link">
                        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 1 Link" --><a href="#">
            <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
            </a>

                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="featured">
                    <div class="featured-text-container">
                        <div class="featured-title">
                             <h2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 2 Header" -->Title 3<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-description">
                            <p>
                                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 2 Description" -->Description 3
                                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-link"><a href="#">
                        <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
                        </a>

                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="featured">
                    <div class="featured-text-container">
                        <div class="featured-title">
                             <h2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 3 Header" -->Title 4<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-description">
                            <p>
                                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 3 Description" -->Description 4
                                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-link">
                        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 3 Link" --><a href="#">
            <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
            </a>

                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="featured">
                    <div class="featured-text-container">
                        <div class="featured-title">
                             <h2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 4 Header" -->Title 5<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h2>

                        </div>
                        <div class="featured-description">
                            <p>
                                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 4 Description" -->Description 5
                                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-link">
                        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Item 4 Link" --><a href="#">
            <button class="read-more">Read more...</button>
            </a>

                        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Other Featured" -->
                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle in case that doesn't work (it should but I've had issues with it before): http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/qhk4zj9r/